# Will it be possible to create apps/games in Java SE or Java ME on new Ubuntu phones?

Tags: application-development, java, ubuntu-touch

Will it be possible to create apps/games in Java SE or Java ME on new Ubuntu phones?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, For example, the JogAmp JOGL Jake2 port is known to run on Ubuntu Nexus 7 touch tablet using IcedTea and OpenJDK.

You have access to all Ubuntu java packages that you normally find on desktop.

OpenJDK implements a JavaSE like environment.

You can access OpenGL ES 1 or 2 directly from Java using the JogAmp library for most flexibility, especially suited if you write your own engine.
The JogAmp JOGL implementation is provided by the libjogl2-java package.

You may also use existing java game engine library’s such as libgdx, playn and jmonkeyengine that will get you up to speed if you want to create a game from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

You could write Java applications the same way you would write them for any linux distro.

Assuming you are on an ARM device you will also need to install a JRE compatible with ARM devices, to run your application you would do it the same way as a normal linux distro (because it is a normal distro), `java -jar file.jar`.

Basically, it's not worth it, yet.

Summary: Ubuntu Touch has an Ubuntu core, and is a linux distro. You can write Java apps for linux distros, so yeah, you can.

`EDIT` And I'm not really too sure about how the window server, X11 I believe (though don't take my word for it) is implemented, so I'm not too sure how apps with JFrames would work. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259990/will-legacy-linux-x11-apps-run-on-ubuntu-touch).